# Differences between OWP and OWF and their IND-CPA security

Tags: chosen-plaintext-attack, one-way-function, permutation, random-oracle-model

I am learning about one way permutations and one way functions and am not sure of the differences if there are any.

Also in the random oracle model are they both IND-CPA secure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A one-way permutation is just a one-way function in which the function is a permutation (id est, a bijective function). Every OWP is a OWF, the converse is not true.

IND-CPA security is a security notion specifically related to encryption schemes. OWF and OWP are not encryption schemes, hence they cannot be said "IND-CPA secure"; however, one can construct an IND-CPA symmetric encryption scheme from any OWF, or OWP. (for asymmetric encryption schemes, stronger primitives are needed).

Comment: Thanks for the help! It's a bit more clear now. Can you give me an example of how one can construct an IND-CPA symmetric scheme from an OWF

Comment: Essentially, the idea is to construct a [pseudorandom generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_generator) from a OWF. Once this is done, just use the private key as the seed of the PRG and generate as much bits as your message lengths. To encrypt, just xor those pseudorandom bits with the message. The seminal paper showing how to construct PRGs from OWFs is [this one](https://www.nada.kth.se/~johanh/prgfromowf.pdf), if you have trouble understanding it / are not familiar with reading research articles, just ask and I'll try to give an intuition of the construction.

Comment: The paper giving a more efficient construction of PRGs from OWFs is [this one](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~salil/research/OWFtoPRG-abs.html). ​ ​

Comment: Can't you use the G-L hardcore bit to get a much simpler PRG than the one from the HILL result?

Comment: Okay I'm still a bit unsure son how to achieve IND-CPA security using public key encryption in the random oracle model with OWP

Comment: @pg1989: I think this require one way permutation, which is a stronger assumption.

Public key encryption cannot be constructed from OWF, even with access to a random oracle. For this, you need trapdoor permutations. For symmetric encryption, the random oracle is not needed in the construction, OWF only are sufficient. If it's still not clear to you, could you explain more precisely what you are trying to build or prove ?

Comment: I'm trying to prove that given a public key encryption scheme Π, a one-way permutation generator Γ, and a random oracle H that if  Γ is OWP secure then  Π is IND-CPA secure.

Comment: @GeoffroyCouteau^

Comment: So you have the following: Π is a PKE scheme, Γ is a OWP and H is a RO. Then I think there might be some confusion: what do you mean by "Γ is OWP secure"? does it just indicate that Γ is a setup algorithm for a family of OWP (that is, an algorithm generating the parameters of a OWP)?
What is clearly missing is the relation you assume between Γ, Π and H. You want to show that Π is IND-CPA secure, using the fact that H is a RO and Γ generates OWP, but you've never told whether Π was constructed from Γ and H, and how. And as I said, Π **cannot** be built from  Γ and H (unlike private-key schemes)